# Find number of bits in a data type

Tags: c

I need to write a macro named `CountBitsM`. this macro has one parameter and produces a value of type `int`. The parameter is any expression with an object data type or the literal name of any object data type, so i used `int`. This macro determines the number of bits of storage used for the data type on any machine in which its run. And i can use a macro from `limits.h`. Here is what i wrote, does this look right?

```
#ifndef COUNTBITSM_H
#define COUNTBITSM_H
#include <limits.h>

#define CountBitsM(int) ((int)*(CHAR_BIT))

#endif
```

Second question was to create a function `CountIntBitsF` that counts the number of bits used to represent a type `int` value on any machine. However, i can **NOT USE** any `#define, or #include` header files, or any macro. I also can not use any multiplications or divisions. The hint that was given was to start with a value of 1 in a type `unsigned int` variable and left-shift it one bit at a time, keeping count of number of shifts, until the variables value becomes 0. Here is what i have so far:

```
int CountIntBitsF(void)
{
    int IntgMax = 8;
    unsigned int count = 1; 
    
    while (IntgMax = IntgMax>>2) count++;

    return count;
}
```

First off, i am not supposed to use division or multiplication so am i doing the shift properly? And i cant assume a char/byte contains 8 or any other specific number of bits. So how or what should i set my `IntgMax` to? Thanks for any help. I am new to C.

Comment: Are you looking for `sizeof`, which returns the number of bytes used for a given type?

Comment: `does this look right` - no, it doesn't. `int` is a keyword, but you use it as a macro parameter. Also the title is asking about bytes, while the question is about bits.

Comment: maybe sizeof operator?

Comment: @EugeneSh. In the requirments he says for the parameter: "any expression with an object data type(24,temp,printf("Hello"),etc) or the literal name of any object data type (int, float, double, etc.)" So i just used the name of the object data type int. Also i updated the title, thanks for that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It doesn't look right, but since it's a macro parameter it'll work...

Comment: @johnmastroberti so something like this: int x = sizeof(int)?

Comment: An abstract data type does not have bits, but operations on it. Its computer representation have bits. Your problem is not much related to C, but to arithmetic.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Did you look into [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) ? And what should `CountBitsM("abcde")` return?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Keywords are only reserved in translation phases 7 and 8, so it is allowed to use them as macro parameter names (phase 4). Just bad practice.

Comment: `<<` points to the left. `>>` points to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Macro for Bits in a Type

A macro to produce the number of bits used to represent a type in storage is:

```
#define CountBitsM(x) (sizeof (x) * CHAR_BIT)
```

However, this produces a result with type `size_t` (usually). If you really need an `int` result as stated in the question, convert it (but be aware overflow becomes possible):

```
#define CountBitsM(x) ((int) (sizeof (x) * CHAR_BIT))
```

### Counting Bits

The second question asks to count the number of bits “to represent a type `int` value” by shifting bits in an `unsigned` value. There are two theoretical problems here. One is that the number of bits used to represent a value may including padding bits, and counting the bits by shifting a 1 through them only counts the value bits, not the padding bits. The second is that an `int` may have more padding bits than an `unsigned`; it may use fewer bits for the sign and value. Overwhelmingly, modern systems will not have these issues; the number of used bits in an `int` will be the same as the total number of bits used to store it and the number of bits used in an `unsigned`.

That said, you can count the number of bits in an `unsigned` object with:

```
    int count = 0;
    for (unsigned u = 1; 0 != u; u <<= 1)
        ++count;
```

This repeatedly shifts the bit in `u` left until it is shifted out, while counting the number of iterations required to do this. Note that the bits in an `int` cannot properly be counted this way, because the behavior of left shift is not defined by the C standard when it overflows an `int`.

Comment: `epresent a value may including padding bits, and counting the bits by shifting a 1 through them only counts the value bits` I think it goes too far as for the school problem. We do not start learning math from the differential equations or complex numbers

Answer (score -1):

Question one

```
#define NBITS(type_or_object)  (sizeof(type_or_object) * CHAR_BIT)
```

or without multiplication

```
#define NBITS(type_or_object)  (sizeof(type_or_object) << (CHAR_BIT == 8 ? 3 : CHAR_BIT == 16 ? 4 : CHAR_BIT == 32 ? 5 : 0))
```

Second question:
For the most popular two's complement (but I think it will also work for sign bit as well as -0 < 0 as I remember). Ir is for signed type. Unsigned types are easy.

```
int CountIntBits(void)
{
    int IntgMax = 1;
    int count = 1; 
    
    while (IntgMax > 0 ) 
    {
        count++;
        IntgMax <<= 1;
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", CountIntBits());
}
```

or (also no multiplication :) )

```
int CountIntBits(void)
{
    int shift = CHAR_BIT == 8 ? 3 : CHAR_BIT == 16 ? 4 : CHAR_BIT == 32 ? 5 : 0;

    return sizeof(int) << shift;
}
```

for unsigned types:

```
int CountIntBits(void)
{
    unsigned IntgMax = 1;
    int count = 0; 
    
    while (IntgMax) 
    {
        count++;
        IntgMax <<= 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why DV? Any explanation?